# How to Create same geometry on MouseLeftButton Click on Two Canvases?

Tags: wpf, canvas

I have two panels(Canvas) in my user Control, left canvas and Right Canvas. Now, on Left canvas I am first loading an Image and after that on MouseLeftButton Click I am drawing an Ellipse. So as soon as I am drawing the Ellipse on Left Canvas, I have to draw the same Ellipse with a TextBox on the Right canvas.
Please suggest how I can achieve this.
I tried using Same object of the Class(DrawEllipse), but not able to add the child on Right Canvas.

Thanks,
Prakhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML: Ignore the groupbox

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="-2,45,0,0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    </GroupBox>

    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="LeftCanvas" Background="SaddleBrown" MouseLeftButtonUp="LeftCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp">

    </Canvas>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="RightCanvas" Background="PaleGoldenrod">

    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
#region Control events
private void LeftCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  DrawEclipse(e.GetPosition(LeftCanvas));
}
#endregion

#region Private methods
private void DrawEclipse(Point position)
{
  // Create a red Ellipse.
  Ellipse LeftEllipse = new Ellipse();

  // Create a SolidColorBrush with a red color to fill the  
  // Ellipse with.
  SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

  // Describes the brush's color using RGB values.  
  // Each value has a range of 0-255.
  mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
  LeftEllipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
  LeftEllipse.StrokeThickness = 2;
  LeftEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

  // Set the width and height of the Ellipse.
  LeftEllipse.Width = 80;
  LeftEllipse.Height = 50;
  LeftCanvas.Children.Add(LeftEllipse);

  Ellipse RightEllipse = CloneEllipse(LeftEllipse);
  RightCanvas.Children.Add(RightEllipse);

  TextBox tb = new TextBox();
  tb.Width = 50;
  RightCanvas.Children.Add(tb);

  Canvas.SetTop(LeftEllipse, position.Y - (LeftEllipse.Height / 2));
  Canvas.SetLeft(LeftEllipse, position.X - (LeftEllipse.Width / 2));
  Canvas.SetTop(RightEllipse, position.Y - (RightEllipse.Height / 2));
  Canvas.SetLeft(RightEllipse, position.X - (RightEllipse.Width / 2));
  Canvas.SetTop(tb, position.Y + 5);
  Canvas.SetLeft(tb, position.X + 5);
}

private Ellipse CloneEllipse(Ellipse LeftEllipse)
{
  Ellipse EllipseClone = new Ellipse();

  EllipseClone.Fill = LeftEllipse.Fill;
  EllipseClone.StrokeThickness = LeftEllipse.StrokeThickness;
  EllipseClone.Stroke = LeftEllipse.Stroke;

  // Set the width and height of the Ellipse.
  EllipseClone.Width = LeftEllipse.Width;
  EllipseClone.Height = LeftEllipse.Height;

  return EllipseClone;
}
#endregion
```

Hope this helped.. This is just a simple way to do it.. You can manipulate it as you want :)

Comment: Thanx Max. Is the communication between the ellipses possible if I go with this way?. I mean, if I am reversing the position of first ellipse from the second ellipse in the left canvas, can I communicate this reordering to the right canvas?. thanks for your help!

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, and you are welcome.

Comment: I just try to explain more clearly! Lets say Ellipses created on the Left canvas are having numbers 1 and 2. As you mentioned same ellipses will also be created on Right hand canvas. But after that, when I reverse positions of 1 and 2 (let say for some vector image not ellipse) by moving them with mouse. Is there is any way I reverse the same order in the right canvas too as soon as reordering takes place on left canvas.

Comment: A good idea would be then to create a link between the Ellipse you draw, and the clone that is automatic created. Then I think you should do a moves move event if it's because you want to drag your item around on the canvas, and want the other one to follow.

etc. 
MoveEllipse_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
//Move ellipse from current position to new mousemove position
//GetClone of ellipse being dragged
//Move clone same coordinates but at right canvas.

3 methods :)

Comment: If you want to swap positions of ellipse 1 and 2. it's the same idea.

//OnSwap()
//Redraw/Move ellipses on left canvas to correct positions.
//GetClones of moved ellipses
//Redraw/Move cloned ellipses on right canvas

Hope this helped.